# Jetpack compose RequestFocus works only once

Tags: android, accessibility, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building a scenario where a button click generates a new screen title and content. Per the accessibility requirements, a button click should place a TalkBack focus on the screen title, so the user could hear what the new content is about.

The screen should be something like this:

```kotlin
Column(){
    Title()
    Content()
    RefreshContentButton()
}
```

I use a `FocusRequester` instance to request focus when the button is clicked. This works **well for the first time**, when the user traverses back to the refresh button and clicks on it, the focus won't change.

I've set up an example that shows the issue. With TalkBack enabled, the first button click successfully puts a focus on the respective `Focusable`, the second click doesn't do anything. However, if I alternate button clicks, then everything works just fine.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val (ref1, ref2) = remember { FocusRequester.createRefs() }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
                ) {
                    Focusable("Focusable #1", ref1)
                    Focusable("Focusable #2", ref2)
                }
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
                ) {
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            ref1.requestFocus()
                        }) {
                        Text(text = "Focus on #1")
                    }
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            ref2.requestFocus()
                        }) {
                        Text(text = "Focus on #2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Focusable(text: String, focusRequester: FocusRequester) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        Text(text = text, modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .focusable(true)
            .focusProperties {
                canFocus = true
            }
            .focusTarget())
    }
}
```

Comment: any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I'm running into the exact same issue currently, and through debugging the androix.compose.ui.focus code I can see why.  In FocusRequester.kt lives the requestFocus function.  Its calling an internal function also named requestFocus in FocusTransactions.kt.  In here there is a when statement that causes no change in focus state when the specific node we are requesting focus on is either Active, Captured, Deactivated, or DeactivedParent.

The problem seems to be that when you request focus on a node the first time it moves it from its initial state of Inactive to Active.  It stays in the Active state so that if you request focus on that same node it won't do anything.  Seems like requesting focus on a different node like in your example code sets this state back to Inactive, which is why you can alternate focus between your two example nodes but not repeated focus requests on the same node.

I have not been able to find a solution for this (even a hacky one).  I tried using the FocusManager to call clearFocus.  Also tried FocusRequester's freeFocus function, but this only changes a Captured state to Active.  I think we need a new public function in FocusRequester that calls clearFocus in FocusTransactions.kt as that sets an Active state to Inactive.  Which would allow us to make sure the state is correct before calling requestFocus.  Better yet I feel like when we traverse with talkback it should automatically set the focus state from Active to Inactive.

The latest [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.4.0-alpha04) for Compose UI mention that the focus system is rewritten using the new experimental Modifier.Node APIs.  From what I can tell, however, this doesn't change the actual behavior.  Just how the focus system works internally.  I tried your example code with that latest alpha version and the issue is still present.

Comment: any solution for this issue?

Comment: bump: any solution for 2024?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
```

And then for the buttons:

```
  onClick = {
     focusManager.clearFocus(true)
     yourRef.requestFocus()
 }
```